# Select most recent rows in Django ORM with grouping

Tags: django, group-by

We have a system written in Django to track patients recruited to clinical trials.
Spread sheets are used to record the number of patients recruited each month throughout a financial year; so the sheet only contains 12 months of data even though a study may run for years.

There is a table in a django database in to which the spread sheets are imported each month. The data includes the month/year, a count of patients, and some other fields. Each import will include all the previous months data; we need this to make sure no data has been changed on the import sheet since the last import.

For example, the import table containing two imports (the first up to January and the second up to February) would look like this:

```
 id | study_id | data_date  | patient_count | [other fields] -->
100       5456   2016-04-01              10        ...
101       5456   2016-05-01               8        ...
102       5456   2016-06-01               5        ...
   ... all months in between ...
109       5456   2016-01-01              12        ...
110       5456   2016-02-01            NULL        ...
111       5456   2016-03-01            NULL        ...
112       5456   2016-04-01              10        ...
113       5456   2016-05-01               8        ...
114       5456   2016-06-01               5        ...
   ... all months in between ...
121       5456   2016-01-01              12        ...
122       5456   2016-02-01               6        ...
123       5456   2016-03-01            NULL        ...
```

The other fields includes a foreign key to another table containing the actual study identification number (`iras_number`), so I have to join to that to select the rows for a particular study.

I want the most recent values of `data_date` and `patient_count` for a study, which may span more than one financial year, so I tried this query (`iras_number` is passed to the function performing this query):

```
totals = ImportStudyData.objects.values('data_date', 'patient_count') \
         .filter(import_study__iras_number=iras_number) \
         .annotate(max_id=Max('id')).order_by()
```

However, this produces a SQL query which includes `patient_count` in the `GROUP BY`, resulting in duplicate rows:

```
data_date  | patient_count | max_id
2016-04-01              10      100
2016-04-01              10      112
2016-05-01               8      101
2016-05-01               8      113
   ...
2016-01-01              12      109
2016-01-01              12      121
2016-02-01            NULL      110
2016-02-01               6      122
```

How do I select the most recent `data_date` and `patient_count` from the table using the ORM?

If I were writing the SQL I would do an inner select of the `max(id)` grouped by `data_date` and then use that to join, or use an `IN` query, to select the fields I require from the table; such as:

```
SELECT data_date, patient_count
FROM importstudydata
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS "max_id" 
    FROM importstudydata INNER JOIN importstudy
        ON importstudydata.import_study_id = importstudy.id 
    WHERE importstudy.iras_number = 5456 
    GROUP BY importstudydata.data_date
)
ORDER BY data_date ASC
```

I've tried to create an inner select to replicate the SQL query, however the inner select returns more than one field (column) a causes the query to fail:

```
totals = ImportStudyData.objects.values('data_date', 'patient_count') \
         .filter(id__in=ImportStudyData.objects.values('data_date') \
                        .filter(import_study__iras_number=iras_number) \ 
                        .annotate(max_data_id=Max('id'))
```

Now I can't get the inner select to return only the `max(id)` grouped by `data_date' and for it to be performed in a single SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I'm splitting the query in to a number of steps to get the result I want.

First I query for the most recent `id` of all rows related to the study

```
id_qry = ImportStudyData.objects.values('data_date')\
    .filter(import_study__iras_number=iras_number)\
    .annotate(max_id=Max('id'))
```

To get a list of just the numbers, stripping out the date, I use list comprehension:

```
id_list = [x['max_id'] for x in id_qry]
```

This list is then used as a filter for the final query to get the number of patients

```
totals = ImportStudyData.objects.values('data_date', 'patient_count') \
        .filter(id__in=id_list)
```

It hits the database twice, and is computationally more expensive, but for now it works and I need to move on.

I'll come back to this problem at a later date.

Answer (score -1):

Use: distinct=True

```
totals = ImportStudyData.objects.values('data_date', 'patient_count').filter(import_study__iras_number=iras_number).annotate(max_id=Max('id')).order_by('data_date').distinct()
```

Comment: When I add `distinct=True` inside the annotate call I get the error `'bool' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'`. Does the `distinct` parameter need to be part of the `max` function parameters?

Comment: Moving `distinct` to the end of the query string does mean it makes it through to the SQL statement executed, but it still returns duplicates because `distinct` is applied across all fields (`data_date`, `patient_count` and `max_id`) which are already distinct.